# How to install gdal_merge to run with osgeo?

Tags: osgeo, gdal-merge

I recently installed OSGEO (http://download.osgeo.org/) which included python and gdal. I just realised however that there are many gdal libraries that were not included in this package for example gdal_merge. How can I install them into the osgeo environment?

Comment: gdal_merge isn't a library, but rather an application. You should just be able to download it and use it without installation if you want though. Did you try that?

Answer (score 1):

gdal_merge is a python script. It may get installed by default with GDAL, but it won't work without the GDAL-python libraries which may not be installed by default or you may not have selected if you were doing things manually.

Check to see that you have the OSGeo `gdal-python` package installed. For the windows installer, it's listed under the `libs` section.

Comment: I have installed python 2.7 64bit, GDAL 64 bit core and set the environment path. Python is installed ok and gdal_info can be started within the command line....But when I go into python from the command line, gdal_merge.py throws the error "NameError: name 'gdal_merge' is not defined"

Comment: @RobertBuckley gdal_merge is a python script that can be run like the other gdal utilites (i.e. from a shell prompt). You don't need to run it from within python. You do, however, need to make sure you have the GDAL python bindings installed (not just python and GDAL-core).

Comment: I have installed the bindings but still get "C:\Program Files\GDAL>gdal_merge
Der Befehl "gdal_merge" ist entweder falsch geschrieben oder
konnte nicht gefunden werden." in the command promt. "from osgeo import gdal" also reports no error....but I can´t start gdal_merge from the command line

Comment: I have got it to work now. Thanks for the help. I can´t explain why this now works...the only thing I did was to put the gdal environment variable at the beginning of PATH.